# Проблема с запросами SQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Имею такой php код, его главная цель - создать таблицу при её отсутствии, при наличии - вывести сообщение "таблица найдена".

Однако, даже если таблица имеется, то выполняется часть кода, отвечающая за её создание.

Насколько я понимаю, проблема в конструкциях `if/else`, однако сам разобраться не могу.

```
$HOST = 'localhost';
$USER = 'root';
$PASSWORD = '';
try {
  $dbconnect = @mysqli_connect($HOST, $USER, $PASSWORD, 'sitesupport');

  if (!$dbconnect) {
      throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error());
  }; //проверка на наличие таблицы
    $findtable = 'select * from INFORMATION SCHEMA.COLUMNS where column_name LIKE frmail';
    @$searchtable = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $findtable);
    //создание таковой
    if (!$searchtable) {
        $createtable = 'CREATE TABLE emailsss (
                                             frmail VARCHAR(100), 
                                             scmail VARCHAR(100)
                                             )';
        @$createtablereq = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $createtable);
        if (!$createtablereq) {
            throw new Exception(mysqli_error($dbconnect));
        } else {
            throw new Exception('таблица создана, все прошло удачно');
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('таблица найдена');
    }

} catch (Exception $errmes) {
    echo $errmes;
};
```

Comment: вы поменьше `@` используйте, и главное в нужных местах. и исключения используют для ошибок, а не возврата результата из кода.

Comment: mysqli_query возвращает false, если во время выполнения произошла ошибка. А у Вас-то запрос корректный, выполняется без ошибок. Вам надо проверять, пуст или нет результирующий набор.

Comment: и вообще странно. хотите узнать есть ли таблица, а ищите колонку